# Long text jumps to next line when finding some special characters

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `div` where I need to put an entire alphabet in a paragraph with a character divider `•` between characters. The problem is when the text reaches two particular characters `|` and `'`, the text breaks lines. Why and how I can fix it?

```css
body, div, dl, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, code, blockquote {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-width:0;
}


body {
}

div {width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; border:0;}

div.Marco-de-texto-b-sico {
    border-style:solid;
}
p.P-rrafo-b-sico {
    color:#000000;
    font-family:"Minion Pro", serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.2;
    orphans:1;
    /*page-break-after:auto;
    page-break-before:auto;
    text-align:left; widows:1;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:0;
    text-transform:none;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.entrance {font-size:40px!important; margin: 4rem 0 1rem;
}


.CharOverride-1 {
    color:#cd1719;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;    font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing: 0.5rem; font-size:30px; 
    }
.CharOverride-2 {font-family:Arial, sans-serif;     font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing: 0.5rem;}
.CharOverride-3 {
    color:#cd1719;
    text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;     font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div>
<p class="P-rrafo-b-sico entrance"><span class="CharOverride-1"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></span></p>
            <p class="P-rrafo-b-sico"><span class="CharOverride-2">A</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">B</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">C</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">D</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">E</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">F</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">G</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">H</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">I</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">J</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">K</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">L</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">M</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">N</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Ñ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">O</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">P</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Q</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">R</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">S</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">T</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">U</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">V</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">W</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">X</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Y</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Z</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">a</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">b</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">c</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">d</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">e</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">f</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">g</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">h</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">i</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">j</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">k</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">l</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">m</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">n</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ñ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">o</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">p</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">q</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">r</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">s</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">t</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">u</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">v</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">w</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">x</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">y</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">z</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">0</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">1</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">2</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">3</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">4</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">5</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">6</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">7</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">8</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">9</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">$</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">€</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¢</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">£</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¥</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">(</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">)</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">]</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">[</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">{</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">}</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">!</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¡</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¿</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">?</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">\\</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">|</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">@</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">#</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">+</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">×</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">÷</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">“</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">”</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">´</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‚</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Ø</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ø</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">†</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">®</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">æ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">©</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">oe</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">™</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ƒ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ª</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Å</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">å</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ª</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">á</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">é</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">í</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ó</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ú</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">à</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">è</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ì</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ò</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ù</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ä</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ë</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ï</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ö</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ü</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">â</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ê</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">î</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ô</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">û</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">\</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">|</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">@</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">#</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¢</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¬</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">÷</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">“</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">”</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">´</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‚</span>
        <span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">]</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">[</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">°</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ı</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">˝</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">•</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">£</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‰</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">⁄</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‘</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">’</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">±</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ˆ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Ø</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‡</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">€</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Æ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">OE</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Å</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¶¯</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ˇ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">˜</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">«</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">»</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">—</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">…</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">°</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">˙</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">›</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‹</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span></p></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fixed if you apply the wrapper of your bunch of span tags flex box. And the assign `flex-wrap`.

Add this class to your style:

```css
.P-rrafo-b-sico {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And it will work.

```css
body, div, dl, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, code, blockquote {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-width:0;
}

.P-rrafo-b-sico {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body {
}

div {width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; border:0;}

div.Marco-de-texto-b-sico {
    border-style:solid;
}
p.P-rrafo-b-sico {
    color:#000000;
    font-family:"Minion Pro", serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.2;
    orphans:1;
    /*page-break-after:auto;
    page-break-before:auto;
    text-align:left; widows:1;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:0;
    text-transform:none;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.entrance {font-size:40px!important; margin: 4rem 0 1rem;
}


.CharOverride-1 {
    color:#cd1719;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;    font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing: 0.5rem; font-size:30px; 
    }
.CharOverride-2 {font-family:Arial, sans-serif;     font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing: 0.5rem;}
.CharOverride-3 {
    color:#cd1719;
    text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;     font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
<p class="P-rrafo-b-sico entrance"><span class="CharOverride-1"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></span></p>
            <p class="P-rrafo-b-sico"><span class="CharOverride-2">A</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">B</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">C</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">D</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">E</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">F</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">G</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">H</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">I</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">J</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">K</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">L</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">M</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">N</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Ñ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">O</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">P</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Q</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">R</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">S</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">T</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">U</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">V</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">W</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">X</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Y</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Z</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">a</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">b</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">c</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">d</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">e</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">f</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">g</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">h</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">i</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">j</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">k</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">l</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">m</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">n</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ñ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">o</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">p</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">q</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">r</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">s</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">t</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">u</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">v</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">w</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">x</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">y</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">z</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">0</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">1</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">2</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">3</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">4</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">5</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">6</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">7</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">8</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">9</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">$</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">€</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¢</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">£</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¥</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">(</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">)</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">]</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">[</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">{</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">}</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">!</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¡</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¿</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">?</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">\\</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">|</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">@</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">#</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">+</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">×</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">÷</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">“</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">”</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">´</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‚</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Ø</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ø</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">†</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">®</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">æ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">©</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">oe</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">™</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ƒ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ª</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Å</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">å</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ª</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">á</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">é</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">í</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ó</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ú</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">à</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">è</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ì</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ò</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ù</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ä</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ë</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ï</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ö</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ü</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">â</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ê</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">î</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ô</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">û</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">\</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">|</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">@</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">#</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¢</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¬</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">÷</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">“</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">”</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">´</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‚</span>
        <span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">]</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">[</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">°</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ı</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">˝</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">•</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">£</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‰</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">⁄</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‘</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">’</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">±</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ˆ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Ø</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‡</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">€</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Æ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">OE</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">Å</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">¶¯</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">ˇ</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">˜</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">«</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">»</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">—</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">…</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">°</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">˙</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">›</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span><span class="CharOverride-2">‹</span><span class="CharOverride-1">•</span></p></div>

Return to post
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `white-space: nowrap;`.

It's confusing, but this `white-space` CSS property very important to controlling word wrap, which you'd think `word-wrap` by itself would take care of.

Comment: With 'white-space: nowrap;' the entire alphabet gets into a single line, I need it framed inside the div

Comment: Then just use `white-space: nowrap;` on the trouble spots where the work break is happening, but you don't want it to happen. Those particular characters are being treated as valid places for automatic word breaks to happen.